# NSToolbar segmented control like finder

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem, nssegmentedcontrol

I'm updating and older macOS Application using newer NSToolbar feature like using `NSSearchToolbarItem` instead of manually creating it by setting the view of `NSToolbarItem` to `NSSearchField`.
Currently the same is done for a `NSToolbarItem` containing a segmented control -> `NSToolbarItem` + custom view.

I've seen finder has the feature that the segmented control collapses if the toolbar wouldn't fit all the items anymore. How can i get this behaviour?

[image] --> [image]

Comment: The [`NSSegmentedControl.activeCompressionOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssegmentedcontrol/2952062-activecompressionoptions) look promising

Comment: Tried it but didn't work :/

Comment: The apple developer forums might be a good place to cross-post. They have good access to framework-specific information like this. They're also keen on evangelizing new platform features, so they would be happy to help you

Comment: Depending on which Xcode version you are using, you don't want to do that.

Comment: @ElTomato what do you mean by that? Backwards compatibility is not an issue.